# Paypal Soap request : How to test a serviece in soapui with good header parameters?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, soapui

I try to test some paypal services in soapUi whith this location https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay.

I generate my user/password/signature in sandbox environnement. I put this request with values generated :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:ap="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<soapenv:Header>
<RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"> 
<Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"> 
<Username>email@test.fr</Username> 
<Password>1378372813</Password> 
<Signature>AUM6025PrUAhjJbx1wnRiHOOgrv4AQc1xL50M13g83QoPe4uaxaBQJR.</Signature>     
<Subject /> 
</Credentials> 
</RequesterCredentials>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ap:PayRequest>
<requestEnvelope>
<errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
<!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
</requestEnvelope>

<actionType>PAY</actionType>
<cancelUrl>cancelurl</cancelUrl>
<currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
<receiverList>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<receiver>
<amount>2</amount>
<!--Optional:-->
<email>test@test.fr</email>

<!--Optional:-->
<paymentType>PERSONAL</paymentType>
</receiver>
</receiverList>
<returnUrl>urlReturn</returnUrl>
</ap:PayRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response is : 
    
    2013-09-05T02:57:40.738-07:00
    Failure
    fb8c36a4b879d
    6941298
    
    
    520003
    PLATFORM
    Application
    Error
    Application
    Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.

Can you tell me please if I forget soap header parameters?

Regards.

Stevens

Comment: Instead of giving the authentication details in the soap header try giving them as http headers. See [this](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html) for adding custom headers to request.

Comment: If my suggestion worked for you, could you mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving the authentication details in the soap header try giving them as http headers. See [this](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html) for adding custom headers to request